# Mysql: query to get average, maximum and minimum from date range

Tags: mysql

I have a table with just three fields:

```
userID (integer, key, autoincrement)
date (Y-m-d format)
hits (integer)
```

in which I populate data every day (userID and date are unique) so i have values like:

```
1 | '2016-01-01' | 200
1 | '2016-01-02' | 289
2 | '2016-01-15' | 389
2 | '2016-01-16' | 390
....
```

How could I get:

- Average daily hits for last week?
- Average weekly hits for last month?
- Max daily hits for last week
- Min daily hits for last week

t h a n k s

Comment: writing a query would be a good start. tip: use [aggregate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html) functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT AVG(hits) FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN 'beginning' and 'end';
```

here: 'beginning' is the start date of week or month in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd'; 'end' is the same, but for the end date.

```
SELECT MAX(hits) FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN 'beginning' and 'end';
SELECT MIN(hits) FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN 'beginning' and 'end';
```

Examples:

```
SELECT AVG(hits) FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-31';
SELECT MAX(hits) FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-31';
```

Comment: Thank you Leo. I missed to clarify that my table stores accumulated data (sorry about that) so that:

Day 1 contains data until day1 and not only day 1's data.
Day 2 contains acummulated data until day 2.

This way AVG would give me an average including acummulated data. Is there something i could use to get AVG, MAX or MIN straight from mysql? Otherwise i think i will need to get all data within each time period and then calculate AVG, MIN and MAX with PHP by substracting each date hits by their predecessors

Comment: Oh, well, If I understood it correctly, your actual date entry (per record) does not match the data in some other columns one-to-one. So, for a given date you have an 'accumulated' from other dates number of hits, for example. In this case I would say that the best solution is to clean the data to handle it easier. The best would probably be either change the way your database is populated with data, so you could handle it easier later or write a script to 'parse' your data(in case you have too much important data already, and you probably do).

Comment: Thanks again @LeoSkhrnkv

Answer (score 1):

For the Average daily hits for last week, try doing:

```
SELECT date, AVG(hits) 
FROM table 
WHERE date <= '2016-03-19' AND date >= '2016-03-13' 
GROUP BY date
```

Max and Min, substitute "AVG" for "MAX" or "MIN".